# For which ordinal $b$ does $b=\cup 2$ hold true?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For which ordinal $b$ does $b=\cup 2$ hold true, where $2\in \Bbb{N}$?

Guess*: I was thinking the ordinal $b=2$ would be sufficient because when you take the union of 2 it's {0,1}, which is just $2$.

Answer (score 1):

The union doesn't make a subset. When we write $\bigcup 2$, we mean the union of all the elements of $2$, which is to say $0\cup 1$. That's $1$, at least for the von Neumann construction of the ordinals.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the von Neumann ordinals, then $\bigcup2=0\cup 1$
as $2=\{0,1\}$. Then $0=\emptyset$ and $1=\{0\}$ so that $\bigcup2=\{0\}=1$.

Comment: Yes: $\bigcup(n+1)=n$.